# How can I get ConnectionString form appsettings.json in a class?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to connect to my database without hardcoding the connectionstring. This is what Ive come up with, is there any smart way to get the ConnectionString?

SecurityDAO class:

```
public class SecurityDAO
    {
        internal bool FindByUser(UserModel user)
        {
            string connectionString = "";
            bool success = false;

            string queryString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(queryString, connection);

                command.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.Username;
                command.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.Password;

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        success = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        success = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            return success;
        }
    }
```

SecurityService class:

```
public class SecurityService
    {
        SecurityDAO daoService = new SecurityDAO();

        public bool Authenticate(UserModel user)
        {
            return daoService.FindByUser(user);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "And I don't know why" well, why should it not? What would you expect it to be instead? You never set it. Did you mean to somehow inject it, maybe via the constructor?

Comment: You should learn C# basics first.

Comment: Ive updated the code, I cannot initialize it with a constructor sins I dont know what argument I sould pass to the SecurityDAO.

Comment: There are various ways of doing it. The one I prefer is using `IOptions<T>` where T is a class(structure of your appsettings.json). You could configure various parts of appsettings.json and inject whatever you need on demand. You can find more on MSDN.

Comment: @MaxK123 ASP.NET Core uses DI to pass services. Your classes `SecurityDAO` and `SecurityService` are examples of a poor design. Instead of creating a new instance of `SecurityDAO` before a `SecurityService` constructor call, you actually need to inject it inside `SecurityService` constructor.

Comment: @dekanidze If they are examples of poor design, how would you design them "appropriately"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DI to get IConfiguration  in somewhere you use SecurityService and pass IConfiguration to SecurityService.Authenticate.Here is a demo:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
           
            services.AddScoped<SecurityService, SecurityService>();

        }
```

Controller:

```
public class Test2Controller : Controller
    {
        IConfiguration _Configuration;
        SecurityService _securityService;
        public Test2Controller(IConfiguration Configuration, SecurityService securityService) {
            _Configuration = Configuration;
            _securityService = securityService;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var s=_securityService.Authenticate(new UserModel(), _Configuration);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

SecurityService:

```
SecurityDAO daoService = new SecurityDAO();

        public bool Authenticate(UserModel user,IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            return daoService.FindByUser(user, Configuration);
        }
```

SecurityDAO:

```
public class SecurityDAO
    {
        internal bool FindByUser(UserModel user, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            return true;
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject this using the constructor

```
public SecurityDAO(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I call my class SecurityDAO in a SecurityService where I create a new SecurityDAO `SecurityDAO daoService = new SecurityDAO();`, so when I call the SecurityDAO in my SecurityService I need an argument. I get the following error:              `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'SecurityDAO.SecurityDAO(IConfiguration)`

Comment: Ouch, `this`? O_o

Comment: You cant manually initialize nothing that depends of dependency injection, then you need a constructor in SecurityService with SecurityDAO parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use DI, you can get the data in appsettings.json in this way:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("XXXX");
```